# ListBox transition when visibility is changed

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, listbox, transition

In my application I have a `ListBox` with some `StackPanel`s in it, and within these `StackPanel`s, a header, and a `ListBox` with it's `visibility` set to `collapsed`

When the `ListBox` which has `Collapsed` visability is set to `Visible` I would like it to enter with an animation, however the technique I usually use for these sorts of things doesn't seem to work.

```
listBoxOfSongs.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

SlideTransition slideTransition = new SlideTransition();
slideTransition.Mode = SlideTransitionMode.SlideDownFadeIn;
ITransition transition = slideTransition.GetTransition(listBoxOfSongs);
transition.Completed += delegate
{
    transition.Stop();
};
```

I have tried fiddeling around with it and trying to research different techniques, but either couldn't find anything, or found them to be too complicated.

So I would be very grateful if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong, or a different technique to follow.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have Expression Blend? I would recommend looking at the visual state manager approach.  It responds to state changes or events and can run animations.  As well, there are some fluid animation behaviors that come with blend that help listbox items appear and disappear.

Comment: It probably would be easier to do it in XAML.

Comment: In answer to the first comment: No, I don't have Expression Blend installed.

Comment: In answer to the second comment: Unfortunatly I'm not really sure how to use the transition service in XAML.